# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer (core dumped)

Tags: c++

Code actually runs fine for me, but I have to submit it to someone, and in return I get an error which I cannot perceive.

The following error is:

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer (core dumped)

The error appears to be occurring in method named: `loadLuggage`. I have also checked the code with Valgrind, but no possible leaks were detected. Perhaps I was not compiling it correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int izbrisiVrsto(queue<T> &queue) {
    int numberOfRemoved = 0;
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        queue.pop();
        numberOfRemoved++;
    }
    return numberOfRemoved;
}

template<typename T>
int deleteStack(stack<T> &stack) {
    int numberOfDeleted = 0;
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        stack.pop();
        numberOfDeleted++;
    }
    return numberOfDeleted;
}

class Traveler {
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
    string emso; //used as ID

public:
    Traveler(const string &name, const string &surname, int age, const string &emso)
            : name(name), surname(surname), age(age), emso(emso) {
    }

    ~Traveler() {}

    string getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const string &name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    string getSurname() const {
        return surname;
    }

    void setSurname(const string &surname) {
        this->surname = surname;
    }

    int getAge() const {
        return age;
    }

    void setAge(int age) {
        this->age = age;
    }

    string getEmso() const {
        return emso;
    }

    void setEmso(const string &emso) {
        this->emso = emso;
    }
};

enum TravelClass {
    ECONOMY,
    BUSINESS
};

class Luggage {
private:
    int luggageID;
public:
    Luggage(int id) : luggageID(id) {}

    ~Luggage() {}

    int getLuggageID() const {
        return luggageID;
    }

    void setLuggageID(int id) {
        this->luggageID = id;
    }
};

class BoardingTicket {
private:
    Traveler traveler;
    TravelClass travelClass;
    Luggage luggage;
public:
    BoardingTicket(const Traveler &traveler, const TravelClass &pr, const Luggage &luggage)
            : traveler(traveler), travelClass(pr), luggage(luggage) {
    }

    ~BoardingTicket() {}

    Traveler getTraveler() const {
        return traveler;
    }

    void setTraveler(const Traveler &traveler) {
        this->traveler = traveler;
    }

    TravelClass getTravelClass() const {
        return travelClass;
    }

    void setTravelClass(TravelClass travelClass) {
        this->travelClass = travelClass;
    }

    Luggage getLuggage() const {
        return luggage;
    }

    void setLuggage(const Luggage &luggage) {
        this->luggage = luggage;
    }
};


class Plane {
private:
    int id;    //plane ID
public:
    stack<stack<Luggage> > trunk;    //stack of luggage on plane = all travelers luggage
private:
    unsigned int maxNumberOfLuggage;    //number of maxium luggage on the heap

public:
    Plane(int id, unsigned int maxNumberOfLuggage) :
            id(id),
            maxNumberOfLuggage(maxNumberOfLuggage) {
    }

    ~Plane() {}

    //get/set metode
    int getID() const {
        return id;
    }

    void setID(int id) {
        this->id = id;
    }

    unsigned int getMaxNumberOfLuggage() const {
        return maxNumberOfLuggage;
    }

    void setMaxNumberOfLuggage(unsigned int maxNumberOfLuggage) {
        this->maxNumberOfLuggage = maxNumberOfLuggage;
    }

    void loadLuggage(queue<Luggage> &luggages) {
        //TODO: implementation
        while (luggages.empty() == false) {
            stack<Luggage> pallet; //certain number of luggage on pallet
            for (int i = 0; i < this->maxNumberOfLuggage; i++) {
                Luggage luggage = luggages.front();
                pallet.push(luggage);
                luggages.pop();
            }
            this->trunk.push(pallet); //loading in trunk
        }
    }

    queue<Luggage> unloadLuggage() {
        //TODO: implementation
        queue<Luggage> unloadingLuggage;
        while (trunk.empty() == false) {
            stack<Luggage> pallet = trunk.top();
            trunk.pop();

            for (int i = 0; i < pallet.size(); i++) {
                unloadingLuggage.push(pallet.top());
                pallet.pop();
            }
        }
        return unloadingLuggage;    //HACK: dummy return
    }
};

class Airline {
public:
    queue<BoardingTicket> boardingPeople;    //people waiting to board on a plane
    queue<Luggage> unloadedLuggage;

    Airline() {}

    ~Airline() {}

    void split(queue<BoardingTicket> &travelers, queue<BoardingTicket> &businessTravelers,
               queue<BoardingTicket> &economyTravelers) {
        //TODO: implementation
        while (travelers.empty() == false) {
            BoardingTicket traveler = travelers.front(); //izbira prvega potnika

            if (traveler.getTravelClass() == ECONOMY) {
                economyTravelers.push(traveler);
            } else if (traveler.getTravelClass() == BUSINESS) {
                businessTravelers.push(traveler);
            }

            travelers.pop(); //traveler vkrcan
        }
    }

    queue<BoardingTicket> merge(queue<BoardingTicket> &businessTravelers, queue<BoardingTicket> &economyTravelers) {
        //TODO: implementation

        queue<BoardingTicket> merged;

        while (economyTravelers.empty() == false) {
            BoardingTicket first = economyTravelers.front();
            merged.push(first);
            economyTravelers.pop();
        }

        while (businessTravelers.empty() == false) {
            BoardingTicket first = businessTravelers.front();
            merged.push(first);
            businessTravelers.pop();
        }

        return merged;    //HACK: dummy return
        return queue<BoardingTicket>();    //HACK: dummy return
    }

    queue<BoardingTicket> edit(queue<BoardingTicket> &waitingQueue) {
        queue<BoardingTicket> businessTravelers;
        queue<BoardingTicket> economyTravelers;

        split(waitingQueue, businessTravelers, economyTravelers);

        return merge(businessTravelers, economyTravelers);
    }


    void opravilaPriLetu(queue<BoardingTicket> readyPassengers,
                         queue<Luggage> appliedLuggage,
                         Plane lt) {
        if (boardingPeople.size() != 0)
            izbrisiVrsto(boardingPeople);
        if (unloadedLuggage.size() != 0)
            izbrisiVrsto(unloadedLuggage);

        boardingPeople = edit(readyPassengers);

        lt.loadLuggage(appliedLuggage);

        //flying to destination

        unloadedLuggage = lt.unloadLuggage();
    }
};

bool MergeExclusivelyInBusinessClass() {

    queue<BoardingTicket> business;
    int luggageID = 0;
    Traveler pt1("Victor", "Candice", 25, "1111111111111");
    TravelClass pr1 = BUSINESS;
    Luggage k1(luggageID++);
    BoardingTicket kzv1(pt1, pr1, k1);
    business.push(kzv1);

    Traveler pt2("Charles", "Sennet", 17, "1111111111112");
    TravelClass pr2 = BUSINESS;
    Luggage k2(luggageID++);
    BoardingTicket kzv2(pt2, pr2, k2);
    business.push(kzv2);

    Traveler pt3("Marc", "Cooper", 18, "1111111111113");
    TravelClass pr3 = BUSINESS;
    Luggage k3(luggageID++);
    BoardingTicket kzv3(pt3, pr3, k3);
    business.push(kzv3);

    Traveler pt4("Frank", "McLorre", 45, "1111111111114");
    TravelClass pr4 = BUSINESS;
    Luggage k4(luggageID++);
    BoardingTicket kzv4(pt4, pr4, k4);
    business.push(kzv4);

    queue<BoardingTicket> economy;
    queue<BoardingTicket> mergeExpected = business;

    Airline ld;
    queue<BoardingTicket> actuallyMerged = ld.merge(business, economy);

    if (mergeExpected.size() != actuallyMerged.size()) {
        cout << "Metoda merge() did not fulfill did not fullfill with correct number of passenger ("
             << (int) mergeExpected.size() << "), but with " << (int) actuallyMerged.size() << " travelers." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    while (!mergeExpected.empty() && !actuallyMerged.empty()) {
        BoardingTicket actual = actuallyMerged.front();
        actuallyMerged.pop();

        BoardingTicket expected = mergeExpected.front();
        mergeExpected.pop();

        Traveler expectedP = expected.getTraveler();
        Traveler actualP = actual.getTraveler();

        TravelClass expectedPR = expected.getTravelClass();
        TravelClass actualyPR = actual.getTravelClass();

        Luggage expectedK = expected.getLuggage();
        Luggage actualyK = actual.getLuggage();

        if (expectedP.getEmso() != actualP.getEmso() || expectedP.getAge() != actualP.getAge() ||
            expectedP.getSurname() !=
            actualP.getSurname() ||
            expectedP.getName() !=
            actualP.getName() || expectedPR != actualyPR ||
            expectedK.getLuggageID() !=
            actualyK.getLuggageID()) {
            cout << "Metoda merge() did not fill up expected queue of merged travelers with travelers that were given."
                 << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argn, char **args) {


    if (MergeExclusivelyInBusinessClass())
        cout << "Method merge() is successful." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Method merge() failed." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have troubles comprehending an error, and I'm not really sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

***EDIT 1***

I have been notified that error could be caused by for loop itself, because queue/stack size is constantly changing, therefore it is recommended to use while loop instead.

***EDIT 2***

I have finally managed to discover where exactly the problems appear:

[Errors_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ack56.png)

Comment: Ask whoever told you there's an error for more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information about the error, its probable the invalid pointer error is occurring in the for-loop of the loadLuggage function. The first line of the for-loop accesses the front element of the luggages queue without checking if the queue is empty. Therefore, if the variable "maxNumberOfLuggage" has been set to a value that is greater than the size of the queue, you will get an invalid pointer error. Try modifying the for-loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->maxNumberOfLuggage; i++) {
    Luggage luggage = luggages.front();
    pallet.push(luggage);
    luggages.pop();
    if(luggages.empty()) break; //add this line of code
}
```

This may solve your problem.

If not, please provide more information on the error.